# Updating CollectionView with NSFetchedResultsController

Tags: objective-c, xcode, nsfetchedresultscontroller, nscollectionview

I have a UICollectionView that needs to be updated when the model has changed.

It is subscribed to the notification center in order to do so:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(modeloActualizado:) name:NSManagedObjectContextObjectsDidChangeNotification object:self.contexto];
}
```

The UICollectionViewController connects to the model through a NSFetchedResultsController that is meant to return a list of the entities "Plaza" whose "ocupada" value is 1 (it is a boolean).

```
-(NSFetchedResultsController*) frController{

    if(_frController == nil){

        NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc]init];
        NSEntityDescription *entidad = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Plaza" inManagedObjectContext:self.contexto];
        request.entity = entidad;
        request.fetchBatchSize = 10;

        // Añadir un predicado para filtrar por plazas ocupadas
        request.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ocupada == 1"];//%@",[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES]];

        // Ordenar por numero de plaza
        NSSortDescriptor *ordenPorNumero = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"numero" ascending:YES];
        NSArray *descriptores = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:ordenPorNumero, nil];
        [request setSortDescriptors:descriptores];

        // Crear el FetchedResultsController
        //[NSFetchedResultsController deleteCacheWithName:@"Coleccion"];
        _frController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:request managedObjectContext:self.contexto sectionNameKeyPath:nil cacheName:@"Coleccion"];
        _frController.delegate = self;

        NSError *error = nil;
        if(![self.frController performFetch:&error]){
            NSLog(@"Ha ocurrido un error: %@ %@",error,[error userInfo]);
            abort();
        }
    }

    return _frController;

}
```

The method called when the model changed does reload the CollectionView data:

```
-(void)modeloActualizado:(NSNotification *) notificacion{
    [self.collectionView reloadData];
}
```

The problem is, if I change any of the values of an entity, those changes are shown in the CollectionView, but if I change the entity boolean value "ocupada" to NO, it will still appear into the CollectionView until the App is closed and opened again.

Am I doing something wrong? I don't know why the NSFetchedResultsController is returning the same amount of objects even though one of them no longer matches the predicate condition.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: OK, I have been thinking about this for hours and couldn't get to see the solution, but as soon as I posted the question I realized I'm asking if `_frController == nil` in order to reload the frController.

Just needed to do this:

    `-(void)modeloActualizado:(NSNotification *) notificacion{
        _frController = nil;
        [self.collectionView reloadData];
    }`

And now it works like a charm.

Probably there is a better way to reload the NSFetchedResultsController. Will look into it, but the cause of the problem is obvious now. Thanks everyone :)